# Deepin linux multiple monitors workspaces behaviour

Tags: deepin

I want to try deepin linux, but before the installation I want to know if it's possible to have independent workspace for each monitor with multiple monitors setup?

Otherwise, how does it work with multiple monitors in deepin linux?

I googled it and I didn't find anything about it...

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Deeping for close to a year now. While I cannot comment on more than one additional monitor, I can say yes. At this time it appears Deepin uses auto-xrandr, if you are familiar with it, you should be able to set your custom modes. But out of the box, multiple displays are handled precisely the same as they are on Windows, at least for one additional one, which can have it's own work space.